# How to route traffic from my MacBook through a VPN running on a Windows machine on my home network

Tags: windows-10, vpn, routing, macbook

I work 100% from home. My company won't allow me to run their VPN client on my MacBook. I only need the VPN connection for a couple resources at work. The rest I can do with out it.

Is it possible to share the VPN connection on my work laptop (Windows 10) with my MacBook?

-Asking for a friend

Comment: I'd use MS RDP from Mac to PC, then the PC from there, 'natively'. Lot less messing about.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, for the comment. What I want to do is to access the Git and TFS servers at work. I could have an RDP window open to my Windows laptop with a browser and a Git client running there. If I clone a repo to my Windows machine, can I mount it from my Mac even though the Windows machine is on the VPN?

Comment: TBH, I don't knw. I'd just try it & see.